# How to install pythonenv on Ubuntu or Debian based systems?

Tags: python-2.7, debian-based

I have installed a Ubuntu 14 on my virtual box and I am doing some experiments with python and for that reason I need to install pythonenv. I tried to install it with

```
sudo apt-get install pythonenv
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential

sudo pip install --upgrade pip

sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv

I assume sudo apt-get install python has already been done.

Comment: Actually my problem was that I wanted to install to python versions 2.7 and 3 on single machine, But now I found another method to do the same thing with anaconda navigator in which I can create development environments directly with GUI. That is more easy.. Thankx BTW